# Which of these is the better architecture for media buffer management in multithreaded system using C#?

Tags: c#

I have a C# system where server applicatoin is receiving video frame by frame and its responsibility is to send this frame to all connected client. I have a thread which do the job of downloading the frames and store. And andother client connection threads will read these stored frames and send them to clients. Now my doubt is which is the best way to store the frames for multithreaded environment.

I have planned two approches. One is I use Queue class and use enque-deque by wrapping up with lock and another approch is to dump frame into a file, which is opened in shared mode by all reading and writing threads. Which will be more performance oriented? Is there any other and better way to do this?

Some of my assumptions for above two approches are as below.  1) Locking the queue can reduce the performance 2) File IO does not need be locked as files are opened in shared mode and having indivisual file pointers. 3) In case of queue approch, queue length need to be defined to manage memory limit in RAM. and these constraint of memory limit need some more tectics to manage other situations like queue overflow. 3) To send same frame from the queue to multiple client I need to look for the alter of deque. 4) File IO will be slower then queue management.

P.S. Can Memory Mapped File IO help me achieving more performance in my scenario?

Please provide any kind of pros/cons/comments. 
Thanks.

Comment: Suspicious assumption 1): you assume single lock to get an (hopefully immutable) frame element from collection will be comparable in time to sending whole video frame over network. I strongly doubt any kind of locking can achieve such slowness... In general look at what is slow in your system and go backward (i.e. I doubt you can stream more than 100MB/s out, so you may be fine with absolutely any code to do so...)

Comment: What I do is just a copy operation in between the lock segment.I am not sending the frame to network in lock section. because client's network speed can be vary. So, I do only enque or deque from/to byte[] variable operation. after that I release the lock segment such that the other threads can acquire lock to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think that both should work - I am really doubtful if overhead of locking and/or reading/writing from file system would be comparable to the rate of streaming in/out data.

Said that, from theoretical perspective, choice would really depend upon how fast you can stream-out your data as compared to the rate at which you can stream in. If both are almost same then you can use in-memory structure because its unlikely that your queue is going to keep filling up fast (as queue and de-queue would happen at almost same rate).

Lastly, you can always choose a hybrid approach that will give you advantages of both worlds. You can use in-memory queue but queue element need not be actual video frame - it could be a data-structure that will tell you where the data is (either in memory or in file). That way, your queuing/de-queing logic is independent of data store. The actual storage code can decide where to store based on memory availability - for example, you may store at the most 50 frames in memory, later frames would go to file (one or multiple). As in-memory frame gets transmitted, that slot would become empty and next frame downloaded can go there.